# SQL Server ReportBuilder expressions

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, expression

I have the following code:

```
 if (qRadioSystemChoice1.Checked) 
    qRadioSystemChoice = "1";
 else if (qRadioSystemChoice2.Checked) 
    qRadioSystemChoice = "2";
 else if (qRadioSystemChoice3.Checked) 
    qRadioSystemChoice = "3";

 updateDataInfo.AddParm("qRadioSystemChoice", qRadioSystemChoice, "int");
```

In SQL Srver ReportBuilder 2.0 is it possible to have 3 fields and then place an X next to that line of text if it was checked?

Example:

```
X (1 text here
_ (2 text here
_ (3 text here
```

I am looking at the expression builder and I see I have `=Fields!qRadioSystemCoice.Value` so does this mean I could have it place an X if the value is 1~3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, basically. You just add an IF statement in Report Builder next to each line:

`=Iif(Fields!qRadioSystemChoice.Value = "1", "X", Nothing)`

Then repeat that for lines 2 and 3, obviously replacing `"1"` in the code with `"2"` and `"3"` as appropriate.